# Display .html file in iFrame uploaded as media file using Django

Tags: python, html, django, iframe

I'm looking to display an uploaded `.html` file in an iFrame on my template. I would rather NOT set it up as a url to visit in the `urls.py` file, I upload `.html` files from the admin panel to the media folder like so:

model

```
# Portfolio project overview model
class Work(models.Model):
    html = models.FileField(upload_to="work_app/media/htmls/", null=True, blank=True)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR) + "/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR) + "/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
include("personal_portfolio_project.apps.resume_app.urls")),
    path("work/", include("personal_portfolio_project.apps.work_app.urls")),
]

if DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) 
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My first attempt to display it using this `template.html` code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block page_content %}
<h1>{{ work.title }}</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

        {% if work.html %}
            <iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="{{ 'work.html.url' }}"> 
            </iframe>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

...looks like this:

[image: firstAttempt]

As you can see, the iFrame is displaying, but seems like it can't find the .html file (404).

I saw in a few other posts that the html line should be:

```
<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="{% url 'work.html' %}"> </iframe>
```

..and to also add `X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'` to your `settings.py` file, so I did both those, where I now get:

[image: secondAttempt]

What is this trying to tell me? What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I have also tried:

`<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="{{ work.html }}"> </iframe>`

to which I get another 404:

[image: thirdAttempt]

**UPDATE**

The closest I've gotten is using this:

`<iframe type="html" height="100%" width="100%" src="{{ work.html.url }}"> </iframe>`

But it gives me this screen:

[image: fourthAttempt]

I put the url above the image to make sure that it is in fact correct. According to other answers, they said just to enable `X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'` and it'll work, but it doesn't for me. Any help from here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I take back my last **UPDATE** above, what I had to do was clear my cache, or run the page in incognito mode as none of my changes were being reflected on the page due to the cache. Once I did that, it started showing the iframe properly.

Another option I was exploring was to set an xframe exemption decorator to the view that handles rendering the post details page, which would look something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt

# Create your views here.
from .models import Work

@xframe_options_exempt
def work_detail(request, pk):
    work = Work.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {
        'work': work
    }
    return render(request, 'work_detail.html', context)
```

which also seemed to work, but I'm reverting back to the SAMEORIGIN method.